# RDLC Report table footer cumulative sum

Tags: rdlc

Designing RDLC report, i created Table (long table multi page) so i need to set cumulative sum of 'Tot' Column at the end of each page
Please help

I had tried :

```
=Sum(Fields!Tot.Value, "MyDataSource")
```

but it gives global total of all the report, not the cumulative.